# Converting a QImage to a C# Image

Tags: c#, sql, image, qt, wrapper

I have a QImage in my C++/Qt application and I would like to store it in a Microsoft SQL Database as a Bytearray. Afterwards, I would like to read it out with a Visual Studio C# Application as a ByteArray and convert it to an Image Object. To simplify :

```
QImage C++-->Bytearray-->Microsoft SQL-->Bytearray-->ImageC#
```

Is it possible with png-Pictures or is there an other solution for taking a picture with C++ storing in Microsoft SQL Server and read out with C#?

Comment: Hi ShbPap. Did my answer satisfy your requirements?

Comment: sure. but need more votings to vote you positive ;).

Comment: Ahh I see.. :) It wont even let you mark it as an answer? Well, good to know your up and running in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this I would use use base64 as a string to store on the database.

Base64 is often used because it can represent binary data in an ASCII string and is perfect for storing on a database.  The reason why base64 is used it that there is only 64 chars in the set and they are all printable characters (no funny weird symbols)

This is how I would go about it:

**Step 1**

First convert your QImage to a base64 string

```
QImage image; 
image.load("test.png");
QByteArray byteArray;
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes the image in PNG format inside the buffer
QString base64Str = QString::fromLatin1(byteArray.toBase64().data())
```

**Step 2**

Save this string on the database

**Step 3**

In C# land, load the base64 string from the database and then convert it to an Image

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
}
```

Note: The code above has not been tested!